# Could not access the server :pgAdmin 4

Tags: service, database-connection, pgadmin, postgresql-13

services opened to change it automatic
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/) Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
[image: The pgadmitool page access to server do not yet ready]

[image: While services enabling in postgre make disable to automatic]

Comment: If you are using PostgreSQL then why have you tagged SQL Server which is a totally different RDBMS?

Comment: Do you have port 5432 set on the firewall?